# How to make 1 svg to fully link to two URLs?

Tags: html, css, svg

let's say we have a long svg. For example we can consider this one that easy to read:

https://jsfiddle.net/seekman/uvn26kgw/

.bbb{fill:none;stroke:#010101;stroke-width:6;stroke-miterlimit:10;}

```
        <a href="https://google.com" rel="noopener noreferrer">
        
        <g><path d="M425.4,111.6c91.6,0,156.3,17.2,194.2,51.6c5.9-6.7,11.8-19.9,17.7-42.3h71.4l-34.2,166.3H634 c-12.8-47.7-35.3-83.3-71-106.7c-35.8-23.7-78.8-35.6-129.2-35.6c-93.5,0-155.8,47.9-186.7,143.5c-18.7,57.6-23.2,125-13.6,202.3 c13.6,107.7,57.8,177.2,134.3,203.9c31.3,10.7,107.5,15.1,158.3-30.4c7.2-7.2,11.1-13.6,12-19.2l26-153.9H459.8v-31.2H648 l-37.5,186.6c-5.8,29.2-2.4,50.7-49.6,67.7c-47.2,16.8-96,25.2-146.4,25.2c-50,0-76.9-5-117.8-21.2c-40.8-16.5-71.4-42.2-99.7-70.7 c-58.1-58.7-87.1-131.8-87.1-219.5c0-88,29.2-161.9,87.5-221.9c38.6-40,86.9-67.6,144.8-82.8C371.5,115.4,399.1,111.6,425.4,111.6z "></path>
        
        
        <circle  cx="417.1" cy="941.2" r="110.4"></circle><path d="M686.8,1038.2l-77.8,12.2l196-929.7h99.3C842.6,303.3,760,642.3,712.1,827h9.8l19.7-54 c44.1-123.6,92.1-203.9,143.7-240.7c24.6-16.4,44.7-27,60.1-31.9c16.4-4.9,36.5-7.4,60.3-7.4c24.6,0,45.4,9.8,62.6,29.5 c17.3,19.7,25.8,47.1,25.8,82.3c0,35.2-20.1,99.9-60.3,194.1C994.6,892.9,975,953.1,975,979.3s10.2,39.3,30.7,39.3 c15.5,0,32.2-10.2,50.3-30.7c18-21.3,33.7-51.2,46.7-89.7l19.7,4.9c-35.3,99.9-81.1,149.8-137.7,149.8c-50.7,0-76.1-27.8-76.1-83.5 c0-23.8,18.4-82.7,55.3-176.9c37.7-94.2,56.5-154.8,56.5-181.8c0-51.6-18.8-77.4-56.5-77.4c-40.9,0-85.1,33.2-132.7,99.5 C776.5,712.4,729.4,847.5,686.8,1038.2z"></path></g>
        </a>
        
        
        
        <line class="bbb" x1="1279.9" y1="121.5" x2="1279.9" y2="1051.7"></line>
        
        <a href="http://example.com" rel="noopener noreferrer">
        
        <g><g><path d="M1516.5,118.4H1858c96.3,0,178.6,19.7,246.9,59.1c68.3,39.4,120,94.1,155,164.2s52.6,150.2,52.6,240.4 c0,87.6-17.7,165.8-53.2,234.5c-35.5,68.8-87.4,122.8-155.7,162.2c-68.3,39.4-150.2,59.1-245.6,59.1h-341.5L1516.5,118.4 L1516.5,118.4z M1637.3,927.6H1858c70.9,0,131.3-14.9,181.3-44.7c49.9-29.8,87.8-70.7,113.6-122.8c25.8-52.1,38.8-111.4,38.8-178 c0-107.7-28.9-193.5-86.7-257.5c-57.8-63.9-140.1-95.9-246.9-95.9h-220.7V927.6z"></path><path d="M2486.5,999.2c-39.8-34.6-59.8-80.8-59.8-138.6c0-63.9,21.7-112.1,65-144.5c43.3-32.4,98.7-48.6,166.2-48.6 c46.4,0,90.6,6.6,132.7,19.7l56.5,15.8v-64.4c0-45.5-14.5-80.3-43.4-104.4c-28.9-24.1-66.6-36.1-113-36.1 c-44.7,0-81.4,11.4-110.3,34.2c-28.9,22.8-47.3,54.3-55.2,94.6l-102.4-28.9c12.3-59.5,41.8-107,88.6-142.5 c46.8-35.5,106.6-53.2,179.3-53.2c84.9,0,150.4,21.7,196.4,65c46,43.4,69,103.6,69,180.6v390.1h-109v-98.5 c-15.8,33.3-42.9,60.2-81.4,80.8c-38.6,20.6-82.8,30.9-132.7,30.9C2575.2,1051.1,2526.4,1033.8,2486.5,999.2z M2797.9,912.5 c32.9-25.8,49.3-61.5,49.3-107.1v-13.1l-57.8-17.1c-43.8-13.1-82.3-19.7-115.6-19.7c-40.3,0-72,8.3-95.2,25 c-23.2,16.6-34.8,41.2-34.8,73.6c0,28.9,10.9,52.3,32.9,70.3c21.9,18,53.4,26.9,94.6,26.9C2722.8,951.2,2765,938.3,2797.9,912.5z"></path><path d="M3217.5,998.5c-35-35-52.6-83.6-52.6-145.8V511.2h-123.5v-95.9H3165V222.2h114.3v193.1h223.3v95.9h-223.3V858 c0,29.8,8.1,52.8,24.3,69c16.2,16.2,36.6,24.3,61.1,24.3c26.3,0,47.1-7.7,62.4-23s25.6-40.1,30.9-74.2l105.1,23.6 c-8.8,56-30,99-63.7,128.7s-77.3,44.7-130.7,44.7C3302.9,1051.1,3252.6,1033.6,3217.5,998.5z"></path><path d="M3718.7,999.2c-39.8-34.6-59.8-80.8-59.8-138.6c0-63.9,21.7-112.1,65-144.5c43.3-32.4,98.7-48.6,166.2-48.6 c46.4,0,90.6,6.6,132.7,19.7l56.5,15.8v-64.4c0-45.5-14.5-80.3-43.4-104.4c-28.9-24.1-66.6-36.1-113-36.1 c-44.7,0-81.4,11.4-110.3,34.2c-28.9,22.8-47.3,54.3-55.2,94.6L3655,597.9c12.3-59.5,41.8-107,88.6-142.5 c46.8-35.5,106.6-53.2,179.3-53.2c84.9,0,150.4,21.7,196.4,65c46,43.4,69,103.6,69,180.6v390.1h-109v-98.5 c-15.8,33.3-42.9,60.2-81.4,80.8c-38.6,20.6-82.8,30.9-132.7,30.9C3807.3,1051.1,3758.5,1033.8,3718.7,999.2z M4030,912.5 c32.9-25.8,49.3-61.5,49.3-107.1v-13.1l-57.8-17.1c-43.8-13.1-82.3-19.7-115.6-19.7c-40.3,0-72,8.3-95.2,25 c-23.2,16.6-34.8,41.2-34.8,73.6c0,28.9,10.9,52.3,32.9,70.3c21.9,18,53.4,26.9,94.6,26.9C3954.9,951.2,3997.1,938.3,4030,912.5z"></path></g></g>
        </a>
        </svg>
```

I need to have a similar svg to link to two different URLS.
In the example above it's working almost fine. If you click the single paths it works well. However if the cursor is between the single paths, for the user it seems that the svg is unclickable.

For example if you put the cursor between "gh" and the "circle" it's unclickable. Similarly if you put the cursor betwee "D" and "a".

How can I make a svg be clickable also between the paths and at the same time this svg has to be linked to 2 or more urls?

Thanks

Comment: put a <rect> in every <a>, the size and position you want them to act as click-area, and set their `pointer-events` to `all`.

Comment: I did it here https://jsfiddle.net/seekman/uvn26kgw/2/ but the svg disappears if I add a `rect` inside `a`

Comment: ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect https://jsfiddle.net/63L9bcpv/

Comment: take the advice from kaiido. In order to know the size of the rects you need to use the [getBBox()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) method for the group inside the `<a>` For example you will need to add this rect inside the first group`<rect x="109.9" y="111.6" width="1013" height="941.3" fill="none" pointer-events="all" />`